# How can I make a button which pops up and also hides a window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am fairly new to WPF and I need a little help on this one.

I have an application where I have an accountmanager, which enables the user to see all their accounts (by email) in a ListBox.

Is there a way I can add a button which can pop up a window, 
on every listbox item (which holds an account each)?

The button should also be able to hide the window.

EDIT:
I have another way to make the window show, not by button, but by right-click instead. I was just wondering if someone had a quick answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your question is a bit too unspecific. You need to provide more of your code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a StackPanel as your listbox item and have it contain a Label for the account email string, and a Button that shows whatever window you want to show. You can set the StackPanel's orientation to fit your needs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have made it work in another way by just opening a new instance of the window, when a user is logged in, instead of doing it by pressing a button. Thanks